# Crop and Compare two images samples in java

Tags: java, image, imagemagick, crop

I'm trying to crop and compare two images, so I created this method that returns the following string as a command line to the terminal:

```
public static String compare(String samplePath, String screenshotPath, String diffFolder) {
    return "convert " + samplePath+ " "+screenshotPath+" -crop 1010x1918 +repage miff:- | compare -metric RMSE - "+diffFolder+"_cropped_diff.png";
    }
```

**The output to the terminal is something like this:**

> convert img1.png  screenshot1.png -crop 1010x1918 +repage miff:- | compare -metric RMSE - result/cropped_diff.png

But it returns to me the following output :

> compare.im6: image widths or heights differ `/tmp/magick-ZdZuQPMb' @ error/compare.c/CompareImageCommand/962.

My question is, why am I failing to crop the images before the comparison ? What is wrong with my command line.

> **Thanks for the help, I figure it out, I was missing the x and y coordinates so that's why the command line wasn't working properly. :)** It should be "...-crop 1920x1080+x-y .

Comment: I believe you need to read the `_cropped_diff.png` image size as a variable to pass to the `-crop` option.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figure it out, I was missing the x and y coordinates so that's why the command line wasn't working properly. :)  It should be "...-crop 1920x1080+x-y ..."

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks for the help, I figure it out, I was missing the x and y coordinates so that's why the command line wasn't working properly. :) It should be "...-crop 1920x1080+x-y .